# React Conditionally Disallow Prop/Attribute

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, webstorm

Given a Typography component with props as styles, is there a way to disallow other props based on a prop used, ideally by code hinting.

`<Typography heading />`  <-- valid

`<Typography heading subheading />`  <-- invalid

In the above both *heading* and *subheading* are used, however I would like to make it obvious that this is illegal syntax. Currently I use:

```
<Typography type={ Typography.HEADING } />
```

Which works well, but is more verbose syntax considering this is replacing an element such as `<h1>`.

This does not have to be react specific. If there is a way using a linter (in PHPStorm/WebStorm, or react) to conditionally show that multiple of a set of props/attributes is not allowed, that would be best, otherwise I would like to throw an error.

Currently with the react side of things I could check each prop to see if more than one is true, but I'd rather keep that out of runtime.

Comment: You may simply check for the presence of both at runtime and throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Fez you can just check in runtime. If you want to specifically use prop types you can actually write custom PropTypes that implement this behaviour and will notify at runtime however it does not look like Webstorm's linting picks up the errors.

```js
const exclusiveProps = (...excl) => (props, propName, componentName) => {
  excl.forEach(prop =>{
    if (prop !== propName && props[prop] && excl.indexOf(propName) > excl.indexOf(prop)) {
      throw new Error("Component "+componentName+" cannot have " + prop + " and " + propName)
      }
  })
};
const protectedProps = exclusiveProps("src", "href", "children");

const ImageLink = ({
  src,
  href,
  children
}) => {
  return <div className='ImageLink' style={{backgroundImage: `url(${src || href})`}}>
    {children}
  </div>;
};

ImageLink.propTypes = {
  src: protectedProps,
  href: protectedProps
};

ReactDOM.render(<ImageLink href="thing.jpg" src="thang.jpg" > Foo Bar </ImageLink>,app)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

This generates a relevant error in the console output.

[image: Screenshot of console error]

This could be used to show an error by unit tests configured to disallow PropType errors.